# Null exception namespace App in Xamarin for UWP

Tags: xamarin, uwp

I am developing UWP app in xamarin. The application works on IOS, Mac , Android, Windows. I have created UWP project in it according to the tutorial given in developer.xamarin.com. But it giving error saying Accessibility.App namespace not found. 
Here is my code:

```
namespace Accessibility.UWP
{

public sealed partial class MainPage
{
   public MainPage()
   {
       this.InitializeComponent();
       this.LoadApplication(new Accessibility.App());
   }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you added a reference to the Shared project or shared class library to the UWP project? Right-click the UWP project select Add, Reference... then in Solution tab select the Accessibility project

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the app can't see `Accessibility.App`. As you claim that Android and iOS projects work there are two things that can cause the problem:

- you don't have the reference to your Shared/PCL project in your UWP project (most likely).
- you have possibly changed the namespace / class name in the Shared/PCL project to something else than `Accessibility.App`

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by missing reference to the shared project or class library where Xamarin.Forms `App` class resides. From the description this project should be called `Accessibility`.

Right-click the UWP project select **Add**, **Reference...** then in **Solution** tab select the `Accessibility` project.

Also it might happen that the UWP project didn't pick up on the reference, so restarting Visual Studio might help as well.

If all fails, you can try to use class name binding with `using`. On top of the source code file add:

```
using FormsApp = Accessibility.App;
```

And then in code use:

```
this.LoadApplication(new FormsApp());
```